# Sum, product and real part of numbers $z$ such that $\Bbb Q(z)/\Bbb Q$ is Galois.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Let $y,z$ be two algebraic numbers such that $\Bbb Q(y)/\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q(z)/\Bbb Q$ are Galois extensions (such numbers could be called "Galois numbers" in this post). Is it true that $yz$ and $\text{Re}(z)$ are also Galois numbers?

1) I think I solved the question for $y+z$: the answer is no. "In general", $\Bbb Q(y+z) = \Bbb Q(y,z)$ holds and hence is Galois over $\Bbb Q$ (because compositum of Galois extensions is Galois): a proof of the primitive element theorem shows that for infinitely many rational numbers $r$, the element $y+rz$ generates $\Bbb Q(y,z)$.

So I tried an example where $r=1$ doesn't work, as $y=\sqrt[3]{2}+e^{2\pi i / 3}$ and $z=-e^{2\pi i / 3}$. The only non-trivial fact is to show that $y$ is a Galois number; it is sufficient to show that it generates $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},e^{2\pi i / 3})$. We have $[K:\Bbb Q]=[K:\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i / 3})] [\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i / 3}) : \Bbb Q] = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$, and $y$ has [degree 6](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal%20polynomial%20%28-1%2F2%2Bi%E2%88%9A3%2F2%29%2B2%5E%7B1%2F3%7D) over $\Bbb Q$  (actually I'm not how to do this by hand). Therefore the inclusion $\Bbb Q(y) \subset K$ is actually an equality.

2) For the product, this is probably very easy, but I have no good idea…

3) I know that $\Bbb Q(\text{Re}(z))$ is the fixed field of $\Bbb Q(z)$ under the complex conjugation. But in general if $L/K$ is Galois $L^H/K$ doesn't have to be Galois. To find a counter-example, I should at least avoid abelian extensions. The example $z = \sqrt[3]{2}+e^{2\pi i / 3}$ doesn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why doesn't $z=\root3\of2+e^{2\pi i/3}$ work as a counterexample in 3? Its real part is $\root3\of2-1/2$, and that does not generate a Galois extention.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thank you for your comment, you're right! I think I swapped the real and imaginary parts of $e^{2\pi i /3}$ (so that I had in mind $\text{Re}(z)=\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt{3}/2$ which is a Galois number…!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample for the product: Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$, $z=\root3\of2+\omega$, $y=\root3\of2+\omega^2=\overline{z}$. Then
$$
yz=\root3\of4+(\omega+\omega^2)\root3\of2+\omega^3=\root3\of4-\root3\of2+1.
$$
So $yz$ is an irrational element of the field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$. Therefore
$K=\Bbb{Q}(yz)$. But $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is well known not to be a Galois extension.